# How to change "ddd" datetime format to a number view

Tags: c#

I want to make that code to show me a current datetime on my pc clock when i click a button... i did it with that code listed down. But here is my question how can i make the "ddd" (day of a week) to be shown in number, not in words, I mean:
00-sunday
01-monday
and etc. ...

This is my code for the button:

```
private void SetClock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetClock.Click += new EventHandler(SetClock_Click);
            {
                DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
                string format = "yy-MM-dd-ddd-hh-mm-ss"; 
                txtSend.Text = time.ToString(format);

            }
        }
```

What i have to add to make it. Thanks

Comment: What would the number be for each day? The meaning of `ddd` is defined in the formatting rules - this is not something you can control.

Answer (score 4):

```
txtSend.Text = string.Format("{0:yy-MM-dd}-{1:00}-{0:hh-mm-ss}", time, (int)time.DayOfWeek);
```

Comment: Note that this will give `0`, `1`, `2` etc. rather than `00`, `01`, `02` etc.

Comment: Correct. Fixed as per original question's wording.

Answer (score 1):

A format isn't required, you can just cast `DayOfWeek` to an `int`:

```
var dayAsInt = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
```

Looking at the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) page, there doesn't appear to be a format string for it :-(

Answer (score 1):

The following should do it:

```
txtSend.Text =
    time.ToString("yy-MM-dd-") +
    ((int)time.DayOfWeek).ToString("00") +
    time.ToString("-hh-mm-ss");
```

Comment: Whee, what's up with this guys?

Comment: It gets the date day of the week, not the numeric representation of the day based on Sunday starting at 0 and Saturday being 6.

Comment: The question asks for the `"ddd" (day of a week) to be shown in number, not in words` and gives examples of `00` for Sunday and `01` for Monday. This is exactly what this does, no?

Comment: The top answer does the same, albeit only with one digit.

Comment: Oh never mind, I thought your answer was another one for a moment then, yes indeed this one does the same (well, technically this exactly meets the requirements whereas the other doesn't). No idea why you've been down-voted then, but it wasn't me. Have a sympathy +1 lol

Comment: OK, cheers for the reassurance :) (Sympathy upvote passed on to the other answer because he got downvoted too ^^)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to get the day of week numeric

```
int dayofweek = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
```